# Can I set an Objective-C property of Int enum type, from Swift using an Int

Tags: swift, enums

I have an Objective-C Object with a property of type `VerticalAlignment`.  `VerticalAlignment` is an enum, backed by integers:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(unsigned int, VerticalAlignment)
{
   kVerticallyAlignMiddle = 0,
   kVerticallyAlignTop,
   kVerticallyAlignBottom
};

@property VerticalAlignment alignment;
```

I want to set `alignment` from a Swift object:

```
if let textGraphic = internalTextGraphic {
   textGraphic.alignment.rawValue = newValue
}
```

But I `rawValue` is immutable.

Is there any way I can pass `alignment` an integer to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textGraphic.alignment = VerticalAlignment(rawValue: newRawValue)!
```

Note that `VerticalAlignment.init(rawValue:)` returns an `Optional<VerticalAlignment>`, which will be nil if the raw value isn't valid. So if you pass a bogus `newRawValue`, the program will crash when it tries to unwrap nil. If you want to avoid that:

```
textGraphic.alignment = VerticalAlignment(rawValue: newRawValue) ?? textGraphic.alignment
```

or

```
if let alignment = VerticalAlignment(rawValue: newRawValue) {
    textGraphic.alignment = alignment
}
```

Comment: Yup compiler is happy and everything runs as expected.  Thanks for the explanation, as well :)